# Query output is throwing exception

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using hibernate data jpa. This is my Respository

public interface MappingRepository
        extends JpaRepository (ConfigMapping, Long) {

```
@Query(value = "select count(machine_id) from machine_configuration where configuration_id =:Id and vm_machine_id =:vMId", nativeQuery = true)
public Long getCount(@Param("Id") Long Id, @Param("vMId") Long vMId);
```

now in my service class , when i try to get the result by using

```
for (int i = 0; i < vMList.size(); i++) {
     Long vMCount = vMRepo.getCount(Id, vMList.get(i));
   }
```

So I am always getting exception

```
com.sun.jdi.InvalidTypeException: generated value (java.math.Biginteger) is not compatible with declared type (java.lang.Long)
```

**Note:** vMList is the list of VMs as List of Long

Comment: Did you try changing the type of "Long" to "BigInteger"?

Comment: Yes I tried but its a type mismatch , saying can not convert from Long to BigInteger

Comment: select count() returns a BigInteger, because there might be a really large number of rows in your table, and the count might thus be bigger than the max value of a long. So you have to accept that, and return a BigInteger from your method rather than a Long. It's then up to you to use that returned BigInteger the way you want. If you're confident that its value fits in a long, then read the javadoc of BigInteger to find out how to transform it into a long.

Answer (score 0):

Use primitive long (not wrapper object Long). 
Refer Example 5. Derived Count Query in
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts

Answer (score 0):

Actually i resolved the issue by changing the vMlist as BigInteger instead of Long. The issue was , i was geeting the vm List as Long while it was expecting to be in BigInteger.

And I also changed getCount() method to BigInteger instead of Long.